# RTC Post build delivery gets statusCode=400 error on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, rational-team-concert

The build definition is set to have Post-build Delivery when it builds successfully. Build engine is Jenkins and I got following error from Jenkins' `console output` (when build succeeds. It won't trigger post build deliver when build fails):

```
10:15:06 FATAL: POST request to https://example.com/jazz/resource/virtual/build/result/_GI3DokOEe6v_nfZ1GCQ/participant returned statusCode=400
10:15:06 Setting the build status to FAILURE.
10:15:06 Post build deliver failed for build result Queued in target for engine Jenkins engine 2(_GI3DokOEe6v_nfZ1GCQ).
10:15:06 Build step 'RTC Post Build Deliver ' changed build result to FAILURE
10:15:06 Recording fingerprints
10:15:06 Finished: FAILURE
```

And the changes are not delivered.

The version number of RTC Eclipse: 6.0.4

Jenkins version: 2.150.1

Team Concert Plugin for Jenkins: 1.2.0.5

The build is scheduled on a fixed time interval.

Any help is appreciated.

The following error message may be more revealing:

```
{"errorMessage":"CRJAZ0024I An error occurred retrieving from the location &quot;virtual&#x2F;build&#x2F;result&#x2F;_ekxKsDmDEem6v_nfZn1GCQ&#x2F;participant&quot;. See the following exception message: Resource not found: build&#x2F;result&#x2F;_ekxKsDmDEem6v_nfZn1GCQ&#x2F;participant ","errorClass":"com.ibm.team.repository.common.ItemNotFoundException","errorCode":404}
```

Note: I'm not posting it to `https://example.com/jazz`, the actual link was replaced with it for security purpose.

**EDIT:**
It looks like the cause is some of the work items in the source stream are not approved by some team leaders. The error message:

```
    Name: Deliver
    ID: com.ibm.team.scm.server.deliver
    Severity: ERROR
        Name: Require Work Item Approval
        ID: com.ibm.team.process.deliver.server.deltaRequireWorkItemApproval
        Severity: ERROR
            Summary: Requirements for work item approvals not met
            Description: Incomplete approvals: Work item 29721 is missing 1 approval of type "Approval" (Team Lead role)
            Severity: ERROR
        Name: Require Work Items and Comments
        ID: com.ibm.team.process.deliver.server.deltaRequireWorkItem
        Severity: OK
```

Getting this approved by a team leader only leads to another error message pops up and complains about another work item needs to be approved. This is annoying, and absolutely approval of work items shouldn't be the solution here. How can I get around it?

Answer (score 0):

What type of build script is this running? ANT? Maven? Ivy?

Comment: It's a python script. We are building a C++ project. Build succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

IF you really don't need work item approval, you can remove that dependency in the Project Configurations. This is likely under Preconditions and Follow UP Actions in the web client, then under "Save Work Item". Look for "Required Approvals". This means it requires a work item approval before it can save a work item that is in a certain state. This might be set to apply to "Everyone". This includes the build agent ID. Change this to apply to other roles rather than Everyone that do not include the build agent id.